# Factoring a joint conditional probability into a specific form.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have an equation of the form:
$$ Pr(A, B, C|D) = Pr(A, B|C,D)Pr(C|D)$$
but I'm having difficulty justifying why it is correct. How can you get the right hand side from the left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition,
$$Pr(A, B, C|D)=\frac{Pr(A, B, C, D)}{Pr(D)}=\frac{Pr(A, B, C, D)}{Pr(C, D)}\frac{Pr(C, D)}{Pr(D)}=Pr(A, B|C, D)Pr(C|D).$$

Comment: Could you point me to what I need to learn in order to see why the second expression equals the third?

Comment: The definition of conditional probability used in undergraduate probability: $Pr(A|B)=\frac{Pr(A,B)}{Pr(B)}$

Comment: I see that the definition can be used to get from expression 1 to expression 2 but do not see why it helps us get from $\frac{Pr(A, B, C, D}{Pr(D)}$ to $\frac{Pr(A, B, C, D}{Pr(C, D)} \frac{Pr(C, D)}{Pr(D)}$. Could you perhaps update the question to put a bit more detail in? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I can't see where you got stuck in. Perhaps you are worried about that $Pr(C, D)$ may be zero. However, if $Pr(C, D)=0$, then we cannot define $Pr(A, B|C,D)$. I really hope this explanation can help you.